# matrix inequality related to finance

Tags: variance, multivariate-analysis, covariance-matrix, matrix-inverse

I'm trying to show that, for certain investment strategies, it pays to have more precise estimates of the covariance matrix of your returns. I have always took this for granted, but I've been having some trouble showing it more precisely.

Call your return vector $\mathbf{r}$. It has unknown expectation $\mathbf{m}$ and unknown covariance matrix $\mathbf{C}$. Suppose you have two competing estimators of the covariance matrix: $\hat{\mathbf{C}}_1$ and $\hat{\mathbf{C}}_2$. The two minimum variance portfolios induced by these covariances matrices are 
$$
\mathbf{w}_1 = \frac{\hat{\mathbf{C}}_1^{-1}\mathbf{e}}{\mathbf{e}^{\intercal}\hat{\mathbf{C}}_1^{-1}\mathbf{e}} \hspace{5mm} \text{and} \hspace{5mm} \mathbf{w}_2 = \frac{\hat{\mathbf{C}}_2^{-1}\mathbf{e}}{\mathbf{e}^{\intercal}\hat{\mathbf{C}}_2^{-1}\mathbf{e}}
$$
where $\mathbf{e}$ is a vector of all $1$s.

I would like to show that if, for some matrix norm, you have either

1. $\Vert\hat{\mathbf{C}}_1 - \mathbf{C}\Vert < \Vert\hat{\mathbf{C}}_2 - \mathbf{C}\Vert $, or
2. $\Vert \mathbf{C}\hat{\mathbf{C}}^{-1}_1 - \mathbf{I}\Vert < \Vert \mathbf{C}\hat{\mathbf{C}}^{-1}_2 - \mathbf{I}\Vert$, then the variance of the first strategy is less than the variance of the second, or
   $$
   \mathbf{w}_1^{\intercal}\mathbf{C}\mathbf{w}_1 < \mathbf{w}_2^{\intercal}\mathbf{C}\mathbf{w}_2.
   $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't true.

```
C <- matrix(c(1,.3, .3, 1), nrow=2)
C1hat <- matrix(c(1.1, .2, .2, 1), nrow=2)
C2hat <- matrix(c(1,0, 0, 1), nrow=2)
cat("first cond. satisfied: ", norm(C1hat - C) < norm(C2hat - C))
cat("second cond. satisfied: ", norm(C %*% solve(C1hat) - diag(2)) < norm(C %*% solve(C2hat) - diag(2)))

w1 <- solve(C1hat) %*% rep(1,2)
w1 <- w1 / sum(w1)
w2 <- solve(C2hat) %*% rep(1,2)
w2 <- w2 / sum(w2)

var1 <- t(w1) %*% C %*% w1
var2 <- t(w2) %*% C %*% w2
cat("final: ", var1 <= var2)
```